# JBOSS web.xml configuration file with Angular application

Tags: angular, jboss, wildfly, jboss5.x

WE  have simple angular 7 app.I made production Build with ng build -- href .once the build is done we placed the dist folder to the server location. application works fine but when i refresh the application the server(JBOSS) is not able to identify the location of the page ..

so we have modified the `web.xml` in `jboss` server to handle 404

```
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/xyz/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

but the server is not able to idenify the path

Answer (score 0):

You have to set to handle `400` and `403` status code.  Because any server doesnt understand which is root file when your refresh page or application.

We need to configure this either in server rewrite rule or config file.

```xml
<error-page>
    <!-- Missing login -->
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/xyz/index.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/xyz/index.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
```

Comment: check your rewrite module is enable or not ? when your navigating its work but when you hit URL or refresh server doesnt understand.

Comment: Check answer this. see it can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088776/angular-5-standalone-deployment-on-jboss-7-1-1